# Flutter devices not detecting device

Tags: android, flutter

When i try to run `flutter doctor` from Terminal it shows :-

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.8, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Where as i try to run from **Android Studio -> pubspec.yaml -> pub_action:flutter doctor** it shows :-

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.8, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set $ANDROID_HOME to that location.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

-I am not able to run simple flutter project from android studio itself i have tried and set path from **~/.bashrc** still not working any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

When i try below command :-

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

It gives me proper sdk path :-

```
/home/hardy/SDKVRUNDA/Sdk/
```

which is exact in the echo $ANDROID_HOME
**local.properties**

Comment: What output do you get for `echo $ANDROID_HOME` in a terminal in AS?

Comment: actualy i found that "Android_HOME" is deprecated so it set it to "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` should still work. If it doesn't there is probably some other problem. Links related to your comment https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15273, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15114

Comment: not working for me i tried both solution @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: You still didn't provide the output of `echo $ANDROID_HOME` or `echo $ANDROID_SKD_ROOT
`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer check edited question

Comment: If you run `flutter doctor` in the same shell you still get the same output as in your question? How did you install the Android SDK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169071/discussion-between-hardy-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? I'm having the same issue in Flutter v0.5.1.

Comment: try running android studio as administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Android SDK path on `Tools > SDK Manager`

[image: sdk config]

Then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to refresh your build.